# Solve equation with $x$ in the exponents

Tags: arithmetic

How can I solve 
$$8(9^x)+3(6^x)-81(4^x)=0 $$
for $x$ using elementary methods.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I see you added back `Thanks a lot!` which I had edited out.  Just so you know, the Stack Exchange [has decided](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts) that you don't need to add this (you can thank people by choosing their answer or voting for it).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Let's rewrite your expression a bit to make things clearer:

$$8\cdot 9^x + 3\cdot 6^x - 81\cdot4^x = 8\cdot (3^x)^2 + 3\cdot 3^x\cdot 2^x - 81 \cdot (2^x)^2.$$

If you want, set $y = 3^x$ and $z = 2^x$ to get

$$8y^2 + 3yz -81z^2 = 0.$$

Can you solve (i.e. factor) this? (Try quadratic equation.)

Answer (score 4):

Building on @Cameron Williams' method, we divide the original equation by $4^x$ and obtain:

$$8u^2 + 3u -81 = 0$$
where
$$u=\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^x$$

Once you solve it for $u$ then, $x=\frac{\ln u}{\ln(3/2)}$

Comment: Very clever, Mike! +1